# Reading N integers in a single access from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io, sorting, external-sorting

Im trying to implement *External Sorting in C*.

I have to read N integers (fixed depending on main memory) from a file initially so that I can apply quicksort on them and then continue with the merging process.

I can think of these 2 ways:

1. read N integers one by one from the file and put them in an array then sort them.
2. read a bulk of data into a big char array and then reading integers from it using sscanf.

1st method is clearly slow and 2nd method is using lot of extra memory (but we have a limited main memory)

Is there any better way?

Comment: case-1 looks better to me

Comment: but accessing time is lot more when compared to comparison and swapping.There will be millions of integers in the file so accessing one at a time will be slow

Comment: Are the integers written to the file in binary format or as ASCII strings?  You mention `sscanf()` so probably ASCII.  If ASCII, is it one number per line?  Are the integers all the same size (same number of digits)?  If not, reading one at a time is most sensible.  Remember, `<stdio.h>` buffers I/O to avoid the worst inefficiency problems — it will probably be fast enough.

Comment: @PranayVarma Sort at the same time you read is the best way. and save your data into linked list instead of array is more efficient in the sort

Comment: i agree to Mohamed KALLEL, for sorting i suggest B+ tree instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to be more clever than your OS, it probably supports some clever memory management functions, which will make your life easier, and your code faster.

Assuming you are using a POSIX compliant operating system, then you can use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mmap64.3.html).

1. Map your file into memory with mmap
2. Sort it
3. Sync it

This way the OS will handle swapping out data when room is tight, and swap it in when you need it.

Comment: It is however a standard POSIX-function.

Comment: @teppic: Today with a certainty of >99.99999% a programm will run on a OS which either supports mmap, or has equivalent functionality in the form of `CreateFileMapping(…); MapViewOfFile(…)`.

Comment: @datenwolf - I know, but the answer originally simply said use `mmap`. I'll delete the comments now it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below function to read ints from file one by one and continue sorting and merging on the go....

the function takes filename and integer count as argument and it returns int from file.

```
int read_int (const char *file_name, int count)
{
  int err = -1;
  int num = 0;

  int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
  if(fd < 0)
  {
    printf("error opening file\n");
    return (fd);
  }

  err = pread(fd, &num, sizeof(int), count*sizeof(int));
  if(err < 0)
  {
    printf("End of file reached\n");
    return (err);
  }

  close(fd);
  return (num);  
}
```

Comment: Thank u for answering but I just want to know wether there is any performance difference between reading N at a time and reading one by one

Comment: @PranayVarma ... obviously there is performance difference between reading N integer at a time and reading 1 by 1...reading 1 by 1 will be slower compared to reading N integers at a time...but at the same time reading N integers will need much more memory to read entire file than reading 1 by 1.
Or as a remedy in between both cases you can combine goods of both cases....
say you can read fixed size buffer(64K/256k/512K etc) and then perform sorting on the go...and repeat same untill you reach EOF.......i also suggest to use B+tree for storing data that way sorting will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since `stdio` file operations are buffered, you won't really need to worry about the first option, especially if the file isn't huge. Remember you're not operating directly on a file, but a representation of that file in memory.

For example, if you scan in one number at a time, the system will read in a much larger section from the file (on my system it's 4096 bytes, or the entire file if it's shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Sort at the same time you read is the best way. and save your data into linked list instead of array is more efficient in the sort

you can use `fscanf()` to read integer by integer from file. and try to sort at the moment you read integer from the file. I mean when you read integer from the file put it in the array in the right place to get the array sorted when you finish reading.

The following example read from file integer by integer and insert them with sort at the same time of reading. the integer are saved into arrays and not into linked list

```
void sort_insert(int x, int *array, int len)
{
    int i=0, j;
    for(i=0; i<(len-1); i++)
    {
        if (x > array[i])
            continue;
        for (j=(len-1); j>i; j--)
            array[j] = array[j-1];
        break;
    }
    array[i] = x;
}

void main() {
    int x, i;
    int len = 0;
    int array[50];
    FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

    while (len<50 && fscanf(fp, " %d",&x)>0)
    {
        len++;
        sort_insert(x, array, len);
    }
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }

}
```